# "data cleaning" of tatoeba sentence file

Tags: corpora, analysis

I'm trying to automate Anki deck creation for my language learning. To this end, I downloaded a file with sentences from Tatoeba. My goal is to calculate the frequency ranking of each word in every sentence, and then get a **frequency rating for the whole sentence**, based on average frequency of all the words that it contains. Then, I want to sort the sentences in that order (from sentences with highest frequency words to sentences with lowest frequency words) and also add a translation to it, for the other side of the flashcard.

I'm currently stuck pretty much at the very beginning: The Tatoeba sentence file contains tons of near-duplicates. This is not the case for every sentence, but for a lot of them. Just as an example for what I mean, from the German sentence list:

```
11999846    deu Tom sagte, er hoffe, im Oktober zurück zu sein.
11999847    deu Tom sagte, er hoffe, im Oktober wieder da zu sein.
11999848    deu Tom hat gesagt, er hoffe, im Oktober wieder da zu sein.
11999849    deu Tom sagte, dass er hoffe, im Oktober wieder da zu sein.
11999850    deu Tom sagte, dass er hoffe, im Oktober zurück zu sein.
11999852    deu Tom sagte, dass er hoffe, im Oktober wieder zurück zu sein.
11999855    deu Tom hat gesagt, dass er hoffe, im Oktober wieder zurück zu sein.
11999858    deu Tom sagte, er hoffe, im Oktober wieder zurück zu sein.
11999861    deu Das sollte etwas bedeuten.
11999862    deu Es sollte etwas bedeuten.
```

These are tiny variations of what is essentialy the exact same sentence. Is there any way to **clean the sentence file of these near-duplicates**?

Thanks!